# how to move an xml file to another directory if something=true

Tags: python

I found this code and I want to move the xml file to another directory if the xml file contains the string "drone" maybe someone can give me some directions?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:\\TomProject\\Images\\132907650508092287_10.xml')
for elem in tree.iter():
print (elem.text)
```

Comment: `os.rename("old_place/filename.xml", "new_place/filename.xml")`

Comment: how about `if elem.text == "drone": ...move file..., break` or `if "drone" in elem.text: ...move file..., break`